# Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in - index.php on line 23

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am working on pagination. I want to display buttons. I am getting this type of error in my code.

```
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\index.php on line 23
```

I have tried the code below -

```
$page = (int) (!isset($_GET["page"]) ? 1 : $_GET["page"]);
        $limit = 10; //if you want to dispaly 10 records per page then you have to change here
        $startpoint = ($page * $limit) - $limit;
        $stmt = $db->query("SELECT articleId, articleTitle, FROM blog ORDER BY articleId DESC"); 

        $res=$db->query("SELECT * from {$stmt} LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");   //error in 23 line -
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Could you please show more code?

Answer (score 0):

the error is due to the fact that you use improperly the  $stmt var ( an object for PDO statement)   as a string (for table name )

And you have also an error in your  sql code  you have a comma after the column name and before the FROM clause

try use this

```
       $res=$db->query("SELECT articleId, articleTitle 
            FROM blog 
            ORDER BY articleId DESC LIMIT {$startpoint} , {$limit}");
```